# How do I fix Unbound Local Error in Python 3

Tags: python-3.7

im doing a homework assignment for one of my classes EMT 1111 and Im stuck on this situation at the moment. The question that im trying to answer ask me this question: Write an interactive console program that prompts the user to read in two input values: a number of feet, followed on a separate line by a number of inches. The program should convert this amount to centimeters. Here is a sample run of the program (user input is shown like this):

This program converts feet and inches to centimeters.
Enter number of feet: 5
Enter number of inches: 11
5 ft 11 in = 180.34 cm

Here the coding that I had done so far for this program assignment

```
centimeters = 2.54
feet_to_inches = feet * 12

print("This program converts feet and inches to centimeters.")
feet = int(input("Enter number of feet: ")) 
inches = int(input("Enter number of inches: "))
inches_to_centimeters = (feet_to_inches + inches) * centimeters

print = float(input(feet, "ft", inches, "in =",inches_to_centimeters, "cm"))
```

Every time I keep submitting the code I keep getting an unbound local error. Can someone point the mistake im making so I can fix it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you want to do but, `print()` doesn't support the way you're trying to pass those arguments.
For the piece of code provided, the following code may be what you're looking for:

```py
centimeters = 2.54
print("This program converts feet and inches to centimeters.")

feet = int(input("Enter number of feet: ")) 
feet_to_inches = feet * 12
inches = int(input("Enter number of inches: "))
inches_to_centimeters = (feet_to_inches + inches) * centimeters

print(feet, "ft", inches, "in =", inches_to_centimeters, "cm")
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if it’s the reason for the error, but in your last line you use `print` as a variable name. `print` is a keyword in python, so you can’t use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues:

1. On your 2nd line, you are using `feet` before it is defined.
2. On your 9th line, you are using `print` as a variable instead of a function.
3. Also on your 9th line, you have what should be printed wrapped in an `input` function
4. It's minor, but I would suggest self-descriptive variable names.

So with this in mind, let's refactor your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
```

It's a good idea to include a shebang line to make sure you target the correct Python version.

```
feet_to_inches_multiplier = 12
inches_to_centimeters_multiplier = 2.54
```

As I said, use self descriptive variables. This way it is more obvious what their intended purpose is.

```
print("This program converts feet and inches to centimeters.")
```

This line is fine.

```
feet = int(input("Enter number of feet: ")) 
inches = int(input("Enter number of inches: "))
centimeters = (feet * feet_to_inches_multiplier) * inches_to_centimeters_multiplier
```

Hopefully, you can see the increase in readability here and how the centimeters calculation flows naturally.

```
print(feet, "ft", inches, "in =", centimeters, "cm")
```

And this, I assume, is supposed to be a simple `print` statement.

Here's the output:

```
This program converts feet and inches to centimeters.
Enter number of feet: 1
Enter number of inches: 1
1 ft 1 in = 30.48 cm
```